# How to Get content using curl/web scraping with parsing PHPSESSID?

Tags: php, web, curl, web-scraping

I have 2 urls which are linked by PHPSESSID,

```
$main = test.com/report/download.php?id=123 //This Url get PHPSESSID

$content = test.com/report/pdf //This Url request PHPSESSID
```

**ASK**

How do I get the content that is in the second url with curl?

**TODO**

I plan to create a button from my web where when the button is pressed it will immediately download the contents pdf on the second url without opening the first url in the browser tab

**I have tried**

I have tried to save the PHPSESSID in the database, and when the button is pressed the second url will request the data, but that method is not effective because PHPSESSID has access time, in my case the trigger to save PHPSESSID is only done once

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the session via the curl's url using the `<session_name>=<session_id>` format. e.g. `sprintf('test.com/report/pdf?%s=%s',urlencode(session_name()),urlencode(session_id()));` or via a cookie. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Comment: I cant get seasson id its bcs my button at other web, and i hope i can open $main url and get pdf from $coontent url from button at my another web

Comment: You want your button to make a request to your website, some php file. That PHP makes a curl request to the main url which will return a cookie that holds the session id. You then pass that session id into the second curl request which gets the pdf you then send that pdf back to the browser. This is all possible.